# Raise after probation period?

Tags: new-job, raise, probation

I got employment offer letter yesterday.

It outlines the following

1. Monthly compensation is X amount.
2. I will be on probation period for 3 months.
3. Contract is valid for one year and will be reviewable afterwards.

But I am confused. Will there be a automatic raise after probation period(If I performs satisfactorily or even well)? Or Will I have to ask for raise myself? And will it even be ethical to ask for raise as they have mentioned contract is reviewable after one year?

Comment: If it is 'reviewable' after a year, that suggests that YOU might also be able to suggest some alterations, including what you get paid.

Comment: @Kozaky only after one year?

Comment: What salary was agreed upon during the interview process? Was it X? Then X is your salary after the probation ends unless otherwise specified in your contract.

Comment: @Alternatingpulse If that is when your first contract effectively expires then yeah, why not? Part of negotiating your next contract can involve negotiating a slightly better pay. It's a two-way process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Contract is valid for one year and will be review-able afterwards.*

As you are mentioning about "employment offer" and "probation", this rather sounds like, the "terms and conditions" of your employment is valid for one year and will be eligible for review after a period of one year. The terms and conditions include your remuneration.

You have to serve a probationary period of 3 months, where usually there are relaxed clauses for leaving / firing (shorter notice period, for example) and partial entitlement of some other benefits (medical, transport etc.). Upon completion of the probation period, you will be considered a full-time employee and you'll be receiving all the benefits of a full-time employee, as mentioned in the contract.

However, a salary revision is not something that happens at the end of probation, it's a result of a performance review cycle, which , appears to be the "one year" timeline as per your contract.

> *Will there be a automatic raise after probation period(If I performs satisfactorily or even well)?*

Not likely, as it is not mentioned in the contract.

> *Or Will I have to ask for raise myself? And will it even be ethical to ask for raise as they have mentioned contract is reviewable after one year?*

You can ask *now*, even before joining, there's no problem in asking, however,the answer is very much likely to be on negative side.

Answer (score 0):

There may or may not be a raise on completing the probation period - some places pay the "correct" rate during probation and getting final acceptance is just that.

Other places do give a "completion" adjustment but this is usually specified as part of the contract anyway. So, if they don't show a completion bonus or payment then the initial rate is valid during probation and after - until, of course, the next pay round or performance evaluation...